# Apache logging: force logging AH00128 errors

Tags: apache, logging

Using Apache 2.4, we had logging set to `LogLevel=info` and got lots of lines. In there were `AH00128: File does not exist` lines. Since then we reset to `LogLevel=warn` and have minimal entries.

However, I've been approached by people wanting to see the `AH00128` lines, to keep abreast of hacking attempts.

Is there a way to configure Apache to always log certain errors, even when `LogLevel` is set to minimal reporting?

Thanks,

Jerome.

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible to filter or promote messages based on ID or text and it requires some non trivial work to add it.

The best you could do is use the more liberal LogLevel (at least for the core module (LogLevel warn core:info) and then create a small filtering program  to discard core:info w/o the message ID you care about.

Piped loggers can be as simple a shell or perl script that reads log entries from stdin and does whatever you want with them.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Not a solution, but being told "no!" is also useful.